# Tangent line to $f(x)=\ln(x) -x + 2$ at $(3, \ln(3)-1)$ intersecting $x$ axis

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

What is the $x$-value at which the tangent line to $f(x) = \ln(x) -x + 2$ at $(3, \ln(3)-1)$ intersects the $x$-axis?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your first step should be to differentiate $f(x)$ so you can find the slope of your tangent line at the given point.

Comment: $x = \frac3{2}\ln(3) + \frac3{2}$

Comment: $y=-\dfrac23 x+3+\ln(3)$

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you should follow:

1. Differentiate $f(x)$ to get $f'(x)$
2. Plug in the $x$ value in $f'(x)$
3. Get the equation of the line in the form $y = mx+b$ and determine $b$
4. Once you have the equation of the line substitute $y = 0$ and isolate for $x$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You should learn to use MathJax/LaTeX to format your posts, one place to start would be the help center's page on formatting: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.